# Can I use three SSDs in RAID 5 with an operating system install on one of them?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, raid, raid-5

I have three identical 500GB M.2 SSD's installed on my motherboard, and want to run them all in a RAID 5 array, where I would have ~1TB usable storage. I currently have Windows 10 installed and running on one of the three drives, and am unable to use all 3 in Windows software RAID as the OS drive is clearly not an un-formatted drive.

Is what I'm trying to do possible with an OS inside of the array? If so, is RAID 5 the right choice, or is there a better way to do this? 
Is there a way to install Windows 10 on one of the drives and then put them into a RAID 5 configuration -- or should I set them up in RAID 5 via the motherboard bios, and then install the operating system on one of them?

My current alternative is running the OS on another smaller SSD via PCI-e adapter, and running the three others RAID 5, with a mirror of the OS on one of the array volumes, as this results in the same amount of space as what I was hoping was possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up Raid 5 in your BIOS (UEFI), all three used SSDs will be shown as a single ~1000GB drive to your Installer.

Just to make sure you understand: All data will be lost as soon as you set up raid in the BIOS.

You still should not forget your backup.